# System of the Unicode Box Drawing table

Tags: c#, unicode

I'm implementing a function in C# where providing from which side goes what kind of line, it will return one character from the Box Drawing table (0x2500-0x257F) from Unicode. However I've failed (yet) to find a system in the position of these characters in the table, that would make a significantly simpler function, then assigning all possible input to an output in one enormous if-then-else block.

I've noted that there are 9 different line styles (thin, double, thick, double-dashed, triple-dashed, quad-triple-dashed, thick double-dashed, ...) in that table, and with the four direction, with the "no line" information makes 10 different states, which would make up to 9999 different combination not including the "none of the side has a line" case, which in my case would be a space character.

The *easiest* way I've found to implement this, is to make one freakin' huge array containing all 10000 possible outcome, (where the first digit notes North, the second East, then South and West) but I believe that this is actually the second worst case scenario I've found, and there is a much more elegant solution. (BTW This would be hilarious if you're not planning on implement it this way. That is how I feel about this anyways.)

This question is probably not suitable here, but considering the size of this task, I even take that risk:

Is there a system how the Box Drawing table arranges the characters, and/or is there a simpler algorithm that does the exact same I would like to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest/shortes solution I see, needs an array/list of 128 elements.

You declare a struct/class like this:

```
// I use consts instead of enum to shorten the code below
const int thin = 1;
const int double = 2;
const int thick = 3;
... // other line styles

struct BoxDrawingChar{
    int UpLine, DownLine, LeftLine, RightLine;  

    BoxDrawingChar(int UpLine, int DownLine, int LeftLine, int RightLine)
    { ... }
};
```

Then you describe appearance of each character:

```
BoxDrawingChar[] BoxDrawingCharList = 
{
    new BoxDrawingChar(0, 0, thin, thin), // 0x2500
    new BoxDrawingChar(0, 0, thick, thick), // 0x2501 
    ...
    new BoxDrawingChar(...), // 0x257F 
}
```

Then your function will be quite simple:

```
int GetCharCode(int UpLine, int DownLine, int LeftLine, int RightLine)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < BoxDrawingCharList.Length; ++i){
        BoxDrawingChar ch = BoxDrawingCharList[i];
        if (ch.UpLine == UpLine && ch.DownLine == DownLine && ...)
            return i + 0x2500;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course you can add diagonal lines, rounded angles etc and refactor the code in many ways. I gave only a general idea.

Comment: This one is actually a great idea, Thanks a lot! I'm not sure why didn't I thought of it. And to solve the fact that not all the combination's exists (like down & right dashed, or up double down single) it could be extended with a null-able character field, that is only set, if there is no equivalent character for it.

Comment: On second thought, scratch that previous addition for the code, as it could pump it up to 10,000 again. I still like this approach though, and think a bit about how could I solve this.